Migrating from spring boot 3.0 to 3.2 is causing issues with inserting objects into Oracle database
Recently, we migrated from Spring Boot 3.0 to 3.2 and lost our ability to insert an object into the Oracle database. The following is the object in contention:
@Entity
@Table(schema="S1", name="T1")
public class UserLog {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY )
    @Column(name="USER_CHNG_LOG_KEY")
    private Integer changeLog;

    // other attributes

   // where we are trying to save in the implementation. 
   changeLogRepo.save(userLog); // userLog is properly populated,
                                // the id value is not populated 
                                // since we are using IDENTITY 

When using Spring Boot 3.0, we use this in our properties file:
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect

But in Spring Boot 3.2, they have got rid of this for OracleDialect.
The following is the issue we are having:

in Spring Boot 3.0 we were able to save when we used spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect in our yml files

in Spring Boot 3.2, we used
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect but it's not working, and we are getting the following message:

2024-08-08 03:13:35.206 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] WARN
o.s.w.s.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.logException(247) - Resolved
[java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot assign field "columnName" because "" is null]



We have tried the following:

specified spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect
in our config file, and doesn't work
drop the generated value and specifically set the id value, and it works, but don't want to do this.

How do we get rid of the error and to save the objects like how I used to before 3.2?

The only way in which i could get the IDENTITY to work is to change it to the following
  @GenericGenerator(name="increment", strategy = "increment", parameters = {
                          @Parameter(name = "schema", value = "S1")})   
  @Column(name="USER_CHNG_LOG_KEY")

Has anyone else encountered this issue ? is this documented somewhere ?
